# RStudio startup error after installing TinyTex

Tags: r, rstudio, pdflatex, tinytex, startup-error

RStudio is not starting up, after I tried installing TinyTex for an R Markdown file. Installing TinyTex led to a "fatal error", after which I closed RStudio and when opening it again, saw that it gave me this startup error:

### R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 2023.06.0+421 "Mountain Hydrangea " (583b465e, 2023-06-05) for windows

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.06.0+421 Chrome/110.0.5481.208 Electron/23.3.0 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 3221225477.

Error output:

```
[23204:9560:20230612,121409.624:ERROR directory_reader_win.cc:43] FindFirstFile: The system cannot find the path specified. (3)
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*C:/Users/majaf/AppData/Local/RStudio/log/rsession-majaf.log*

```
2023-06-12T10:14:09.540775Z [rsession-majaf] ERROR system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified) [path: %SYSTEMROOT%/System32/OpenSSH/, path: pdflatex.bat]; OCCURRED AT class rstudio::core::Error __cdecl rstudio::core::FilePath::completeChildPath(const class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,class rstudio::core::FilePath &) const src/cpp/shared_core/FilePath.cpp:772
2023-06-12T10:14:09.541775Z [rsession-majaf] ERROR system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified) [path: %SYSTEMROOT%/System32/OpenSSH/, path: pdflatex.cmd]; OCCURRED AT class rstudio::core::Error __cdecl rstudio::core::FilePath::completeChildPath(const class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,class rstudio::core::FilePath &) const src/cpp/shared_core/FilePath.cpp:772
2023-06-12T10:14:09.541775Z [rsession-majaf] ERROR system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified) [path: %SYSTEMROOT%/System32/OpenSSH/, path: pdflatex.cmd]; OCCURRED AT class rstudio::core::Error __cdecl rstudio::core::FilePath::completeChildPath(const class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,class rstudio::core::FilePath &) const src/cpp/shared_core/FilePath.cpp:772
```

I tried uninstalling RStudio and R. Nothing worked.